# WKWebView not showing current version of webpage

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have an app that gets a url from NSUserdefaults and fetches it in a WKWebView.
If I make changes to the web page on the web server, the WKWebview does not reflect the newly changed page.  It still displays an older version. How do I get the WKWebView to forget the old page and load fresh content. If I follow the same URL in safari I see the new page but not in the web view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    myWebView.opaque = NO;
    myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    strSelectedLink = [defaults objectForKey: @"keySelectedLink"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strSelectedLink];

    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     [myWebView loadRequest:urlReq];
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.programmersought.com/article/5469780772/

Comment: If you got it to work, feel free to answer your own question with the solution you found.